# Slick2D: constructor vs. init

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

What is the difference between the constructor of a `BasicGameState` and the `init` method?  It appears that they are both called at the same time when the `BasicGameState` is registered in `StateBasedGame`, so what makes them different?

A follow up question to this is how do I run a method only when a state becomes active?  Initially I thought the `init` method was only called when a new state becomes active, but this is not true.  Note that I'd like to call this method only once at the beginning of the new state, so putting it in the `update` method seems like the wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the first question, I generally initialize all my java objects in the constructor (other game objects, collections, sockets etc.) and the init() method loads images, sounds and other resources.

And the 2nd question, there is a method called enter() which is called upon entering the GameState. Also there is a leave() method which is called when leaving the state.

More on the GameState is found here http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/state/GameState.html

Comment: Perfect. I keep forgetting to check the parent classes for methods that I expect should be implemented.